# Which math class should I take as an exchange student in the USA (OH)?

Tags: algebra, geometry, statistics, functions

I will go to an American High School (Ohio) this summer for a year and I will probably be a junior. I got a list of all classes, but there are really many classes to choose especially math classes. I have to take something which would be similar to my German math class
(Analysis & Function:
sine, cosine, exponential, powerfunction,differential calculus, polynomial function
Analytic Geometry & linear Algebra:
Euclidean vector
These are some topics I would do in my German school.).

My high school in America (Ohio) offers: 
CP Algebra,
CP Geometry,
CP Algebra II,
CP Statistics,
CP Honors Geometry,
CP Honors Algebra II,
CP Pre Calculus,
Concepts of Algebra,
College Algebra,
Transition to College Algebra,
AP Calculus

I am really overwhelmed with all these classes, could you give me an advise?

Comment: It might be helpful if you told us what your most recent mathematics class was.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is too localized and thus very focused on the specific OP needs instead of useful for the general person.

Comment: I voted not to close this, but mostly because I think that something useful will come out of it - namely, rough equivalences between different systems' courses.  That would be a good question, and perhaps the OP could edit the question to be more generic (e.g., here are several classes I've taken, including the one for this year, and what are rough equivalences in the US?).

Answer (score 2):

Most of the German course sounds like a College Algebra class (with trigonometry), with smatterings of Precalculus and one bit of (AP) Calculus.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like Precalculus is the course you should take. A typical Precalculus course covers the topics you listed (without the differential calculus).

However my best advice is to talk with  (or email) the school you're planning on attending. Ask the person(s) who teach these courses and see what they think. You might find that you're ready for AP Calculus or that Precalculus is right or that both are a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I think pre-calculus sounds like it'd be a good fit

Comment: I agree with your answer, but could you add some explanation as to why pre-calculus is a good fit? That would make the answer much more useful.